# how to display another site in an iframe in spite of X-Frame-Options

Tags: html, apache, .htaccess, iframe, x-frame-options

I have created a site that lists a series of links to external websites about a specific topic and then when the user clicks on such links the links open in an iframe.
It works locally but on my shared hosting server every link that is clicked opens in the full browser (as if target were set to "_top" instead of "myIFRAME").
I have tried adding an .htaccess file to my root with this:

```
Header always append X-Frame-Options ALLOWALL
```

and this:

`add_header X-Frame-Options "ALLOWALL"`

as well as this:

```
Header always append X-Frame-Options ALLOW-FROM http://www.example.com
```

In each of these cases I have verified with Google Chrome Dev Tools that the headers were being set and they were, but the pages keep openig in the main browser.

Is there anything else I can do?

Or my only solution to swap iframes for deprecated frames?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Actually I was able to make it work.

I added a:

```
    <base target="myTargetFrameID">
```

in the  section of my main html file.
And I also added this:

```
Header always unset X-Frame-Options
```

to an .htaccess file in the folder of the script (which I read about here: http://osric.com/chris/accidental-developer/2016/02/per-directory-x-frame-options-header-apache/)

Works now.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can't, and there is no workaround. Framesets won't work either; `X-Frame-Options` applies to all types of frames, not just iframes.

The purpose of the `X-Frame-Options` header is to allow a web site to prevent itself from being displayed in a frame. You cannot override it by setting headers on a page on your own domain; that would make the header useless.

If you want to link to these sites, you will need to link to them normally. You cannot display them in frames.

Comment: I am confused... if what you say is correct, then how come it works locally but it doesn't work when I upload my script to the webserver? wouldn't that mean it is server-related? also some of these pages I am linking to are sooooo old that I am sure they don't all have X-Frames-Options set at all (since it's a relatively new thing)

Comment: I'm confused now. Your question title implied that X-Frame-Options was involved, now you think it isn't? A link to your site would have helped.